# C++ template static pointer-to-member initialization

Tags: c++, templates, static, initialization

I have a template class which has a static pointer-to-member, like this:

```
template<class T, T* T::*nextptr>
class Queue
{
    T* head;
    T* tail;
    static T* T::*pnext;
};
```

My question is how to write the initializer of the static pointer-to-member. I tried the obvious case:

```
template<class T, T* T::*nextptr> T* Queue<T, nextptr>::*pnext(nextptr);
```

But that didn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Queue<T, nextptr>::pnext` is declared as type `T* T::*`, so it should look like this:

```
template<class T, T* T::*nextptr>
T* T::* Queue<T, nextptr>::pnext(nextptr);
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you really need a static member variable of a template that has the same value as a template parameter?

The only use would be if its value were to change over the lifetime of the program but I really can't think of any situation were this would produce more benefit than cause confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I really didn't need the static member variable, only the template parameter.

Comment: he could make use of it if he only knows the type. then he can do Type::pnext; (much like those type-defs) but then i would recommend him to make the pointer const. but even so, i would prefer a static inline function.